# Click Event IF statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, event-handling

I'm trying create a button handler which will look at an if statement to determine which function to run.

I've created three separate button handlers which work fine (based on IDs) but I'd like to roll them into one by selecting by class then filtering by ID. I can't quite get the syntax right though. The code is below, thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
$(".btnSort").click(function() {
    console.log('button clicked');
var divList = $(".listing").toArray();

divList.sort(function(a, b){
    //sort by alpha
    if ($(this).hasId('#alphBtn')) {
        return $(a).find('.hotel').text() > $(b).find('.hotel').text() ? 1 : -1; ;
    }
    //sort by price
    else if ($(this).hasId('#priceBtn')) {
        return +$(b).find('.price').data('price') - +$(a).find('.price').data('price');
    }
    //sort by rating
    else {
        return +$(b).find('.stars').data('sort') - +$(a).find('.stars').data('sort');
    }
});

$("#container").html(divList);

$('.btnSort').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

Here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dvmac/h58exqsu/13/

Comment: AFAIK there's no hasId method in jquery, you can probably use .is('#alphaBtn') for that purpose

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion but while it seems to allow the active state to change, it does nothing else. I was wondering if a SWITCH statement might be more appropriate but I'm unsure how I might phrase it. Would I declare vars for each ID upfront in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sth that I would try. I changed `$(".btnSort").click` handler to save the button `id` into `clickedButtonId` variable, that is later used for comparison. I haven't tested the code but I would give it a go.

```
  $(".btnSort").click(function() {

    var clickedButtonId = $(this).attr("id");
    //console.log("clicked button id: " + clickedButtonId);

    var divList = $(".listing").toArray();

    divList.sort(function(a, b){
        if (clickedButtonId === 'alphBtn') {
            return $(a).find('.hotel').text() > $(b).find('.hotel').text() ? 1 : -1; ;
        }
        //sort by price
        else if (clickedButtonId === 'priceBtn') {
            return $(b).find('.price').data('price') - +$(a).find('.price').data('price');
        }
        //sort by rating
        else {
            return $(b).find('.stars').data('rating') - +$(a).find('.stars').data('rating');
        }
    });

    $("#container").html(divList);

    $('.btnSort').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @jyrkim, that seems to be detecting the correct click but my sort functions aren't working and I don't understand why.

Comment: @dvmac01 About the sorting, I think it would be helpful if you could provide us with fiddle or some html so that we can test that your sorting. Your sorting looks very advanced indeed.

Comment: @dvmac01 cheers, I'm having a look at it. I just realized after having a look to the fiddle that the if selection in the sorting wasn't correct. For example I just changed   if (clickedButtonId === '#alphBtn') to if (clickedButtonId === 'alphBtn')

Comment: Excellent @jyrkim - that's done the trick! I'm still relatively new to this and knowing when to include the # gets me every time. The last remaining problem is my 'switcher' arrows to reveal more info work on load but not after. Back to the manual I guess. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dvmac01 I updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/h58exqsu/14/  and it looks that sorting is working now, i think :-) Anyway, I learned something new about sorting today, very advanced solution :-)

Comment: Thanks @jyrkim, I struggled a little with it so came here for assistance but I read somewhere how sorting by a data-attribute could avoid the need for string filtering etc. I was going to have the data attributes added dynamically to ensure they always reflected the values in the html but figured I might be making more work for myself! ;)

Comment: @dvmac01, the data-attribute alternative sounds very useful, because with that attribute you can more easily separate the data that was displayed on your html page from the data that you want to use for sorting. So it depends on the data I guess how useful it's to have data-attributes I guess ( please note I'm not a specialist in this field :-) Another thing if you want to get access to the element id in your click handler you can also use this.id. More info: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-speed-test-this-attrid-this-id/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating `if` statements, can't you just use and appropriate selector in jquery for querying these buttons?

Examples:

```
 $('#test') // query for ellements that has id="test"
 $('.test') // query for ellements that has class="test"
 $('#test .test') // query for child ellements of id="test" that has class="test"
 $('.test #test') // query for child ellements of class="test" that has id="test"
 $('#a, #b') // query for child ellements with id="a" or id="b"
```

You just have to create your selector correctly and put any handler you want, like `.on("click", function () {});`

Comment: As I said in my explanation, I have the correct selectors on three different button handlers but I realised there was some duplication so I'm trying to make the one 'click' detection trigger 3 different possibilities. Am I going about tis the wrong way?